# Reference an unsaved field on a Django model when saving

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-models

I am uploading my media to an S3 bucket and would like to reference the name field before uploading to S3.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
   name = ForeignKey(Person)
   img = ImageField(upload_to='<name>/avatars/')
```

How do I use the name field dynamically in upload_to?

I've tried:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = ForeignKey(Person)
    path = name.email + '/avatars/'
    img = ImageField(upload_to=path)
```

but I get an AttributeError saying ForeignKey object has no attribute email even though I have another model that I would be referencing in the ForeignKey.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer that works here
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/filefield-django-models/

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.name, filename)

class Customer(models.Model):
   name = ForeignKey(Person)
   img = ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```